# AngularJs $http get request - How to show Progress bar?

Tags: angularjs

In my application , i try to make a simple get request. For that request response is very huge JSON(15 MB).

Is Possible to show progress bar to show this much percentage download?

Answer (score 2):

Try this it will sure help you
http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/

```
 npm install angular-loading-bar

 angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Angular Loading Bar. It works automatically for $http requests and does not reuire any setup except adding it as a dependency.

```
angular.module('app', ['angular-loading-bar']);
```

http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/